# What is EMOD_MULTI evaluation mode in OllyDBG?

Tags: ollydbg, debugging

I am testing a program using conditional log, I would like to display the log in bytes of length 12. So I found this [website](http://www.ollydbg.de/Help/i_Expressions.htm) about the syntax of expression.

So I filled something like  [BYTE*12 400000]  in the expression field but it turns out showing syntax error in the log view. So, how to enable the EMOD_MULTI evaluation mode?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using ollydbg 2.01 (multiple expression logging is not supported in version 1.10) 
if you want to log multiple expression in ollydbg 1.10 you should look for modified command line plugin

with that out of way the i dont get any syntax errors if used as documented

```
Log data
Address   Message
7C901295  INT3: [BYTE*8 1000000] = 4D, 5A, 90, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0
7C901295  Breakpoint at ntdll.RtlInitUnicodeString
7C901295  INT3: [char*8 1000000] = 4D (77.), 5A (90.), FFFFFF90 (-112.), 0, 3, 0, 0, 0
7C901295  Breakpoint at ntdll.RtlInitUnicodeString
7C901295  INT3: [dword*8 1000000] = 905A4D, 3, 4, 0FFFF, 0B8, 0, 40, 0
7C901295  Breakpoint at ntdll.RtlInitUnicodeString
7C901295  INT3: [word*8 1000000] = 5A4D, 90, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0FFFF, 0
7C901295  Breakpoint at ntdll.RtlInitUnicodeString
7C901295  INT3: [int*8 1000000] = 905A4D (9460301.), 3, 4, 0FFFF (65535.), 0B8 (184.), 0, 40 (64.), 0
7C901295  Breakpoint at ntdll.RtlInitUnicodeString
7C901295  INT3: [unsigned long*8 1000000] = 905A4D, 3, 4, 0FFFF, 0B8, 0, 40, 0
7C901295  Breakpoint at ntdll.RtlInitUnicodeString
7C901295  INT3: [DOUBLE*8 1000000] = 6.3706613826192345360e-314, 1.3906499416091109740e-309, 9.0908078834789364120e-322, 3.1620201333839778820e-322, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0927898983166535560e-312
7C901295  Breakpoint at ntdll.RtlInitUnicodeString
```